# .NET 7 Web API in Azure App Service slows down with continuous requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

My .NET 7 Web API hosted in Azure App Service slows down with continuous requests. Let's say I send 25 requests one after another (not concurrently) the response times start less than a second and slowly increase by .1-.2 of a second and end up taking 6seconds+.

The Web API uses GroupDocs.Conversion to simply convert some word documents to PDF.

`Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`PdfConverterController`

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("convert/word")]
public IActionResult ConvertWord(IFormFile fileToConvert, [FromQuery] string? password)
{
   if (fileToConvert == null || fileToConvert.Length == 0)
       return BadRequest("No file uploaded.");

   try
   {
       var outputPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileToConvert.FileName + ".pdf");

       var decodedPassword = string.Empty;
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
           decodedPassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(password));

       var loadOptions = new WordProcessingLoadOptions
       {
           Password = decodedPassword,
           Format = (WordProcessingFileType)FileType.FromExtension(Path.GetExtension(fileToConvert.FileName)),
       };

       using (Converter converter = new Converter(fileToConvert.OpenReadStream, () => loadOptions))
       {
           var convertOptions = new PdfConvertOptions();
           converter.Convert(outputPath, convertOptions);
       }

       var ms = new MemoryStream();

       using (var fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Open))
           fs.CopyTo(ms);

       System.IO.File.Delete(outputPath);

       return File(ms.ToArray(), MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
   }
}
```

This API is then in turned called via the `HttpClient` I have tried this in a `using` statement as well as single instance of the client for each request, this appears to have no effect. I do not believe there to be a problem with the third-party GroupDocs library as this works fine in a .NET 7 console application performing conversions locally.

The app service is also a PremiumV3 tier so I don't think this is the bottleneck. I have also tried various combinations of using statements to ensure resources are disposes correctly and manually invoking garbage collection, but again this appears to have no effect.

What can I try next? Interestingly the problem also appears to be worse when the API is published via a release pipeline rather than Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a memory leak issue. As you are doing File IO operations you need to Implement **IDisposable** design pattern to release your unmanaged resources.

Please find official microsoft documentation below.

[Implement a Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Would you able to suggest any changes to help with this? Both `Converter` and `FileStream` are wrapped in using statements. I also tried `ms.Dispose()` in a finally block but this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Best you can do is to wrap deletion of a file in a task and then await it or just fire and forget (it's up to you what you want, but be sure to be be aware of consequences like loosing exceptions when not awaiting tasks):

var deletionTask = Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.Delete(outputPath));

Comment: Additionally, You can make this API async using async await.

Comment: I don't believe the issue is related to async/await. I have tried this previously. Thank you for your suggestions, after further testing I believe the problem could be related to the converter as if I take this out and just return a PDF from disk there is no performance decrease.